# Ruby - Rails - Type Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What does type error mean? I am reading a value from a table with a `SELECT` statement and using that value to pass on to a method.

```
  a = Item.select("value").where("item.value LIKE :posted_data",{:posted_data => params[:posted_data]})
    @h = Issue.ask(xyz, abc, a[:value])
```

TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
I tried `a`, `a[:value]`, `a[:value].to_s`. all didn't work.

```
puts a.to_s
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xa898ba4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `a.first[:value]`

It is because 'a' is a relation in this case, it can contain multiple items.